# Delay isn't executed after creating a Bookmark in a NativeActivity

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

In my workflow Application I have a NativeActivity that is paused with a bookmark:

```
context.CreateBookmark(bookmarkString, this.Continue);
```

Now I want to build a mechanism to send a notification email to the user if he doesn't continue the workflow after a certain amount of time. Therefore I want to use

```
currentDelayActivity = new Delay();    
context.ScheduleActivity(currentDelayActivity, OnDelayCompleted, OnDelayFaulted);
```

But here there is a problem: The currentDelayActivity is executed after the bookmark is called. Is it a problem that the bookmark persists the workflow? If i use

```
 currentDelayActivity = new Sequence();
```

it works well. The full code of the NativeActivity:

```
    public class TestActivity: NativeActivity<String>
    {
        private Variable<TimeSpan> delayTimeSpanVariable = new Variable<TimeSpan>();
        private Activity currentDelayActivity;

        protected protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            String bookmarkString = "Test";
            context.CreateBookmark(bookmarkString, this.Continue);
            TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            delayTimeSpanVariable.Set(context, timeSpan);
            context.ScheduleActivity(currentDelayActivity, OnDelayCompleted, OnDelayFaulted);
        }

        private void OnDelayCompleted(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance completed)
        {
           //This method is executed after the activity is continued (with the bookmark String)
        }

        private void OnDelayFaulted(NativeActivityFaultContext faultContext, Exception propagatedException, ActivityInstance propagatedFrom)
        {

        }

        private void Continue(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, Object obj)
        {

        }

        protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
            currentDelayActivity = new Delay();
            ((Delay)currentDelayActivity).Duration = new InArgument<TimeSpan>(delayTimeSpanVariable);  
            metadata.AddImplementationVariable(delayTimeSpanVariable);
            metadata.AddImplementationChild(currentDelayActivity);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your activity seems very strange... I'm not sure to really understand your problem.

AMHA you should use a Pick activity, with one branch containing your bookmark and another branch containing your delay. So the workflow will continue whatever branch first complete. And you set your "send email" activity on the delay branch, after the delay activity. If you want to juste periodically send reminder email, put your delay+send email in a `while(true)` activity, and this branch will never complete and it'll only wait for your bookmark.

But anyway, if I've correctly understood your problem, as you use bookmarks I think you should override `CanInduceIdle` to return `true`:

```
protected override bool CanInduceIdle
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my solution quite a bit. For example I added `CanInduceIdle` and also added the `Delay` to a `Parallel`. This didn't help to solve my problem. Finally the usage of a so called `NoPersistHandle` solved my Problem.

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
{
     NoPersistHandle handle = noPersistHandle.Get(context);
     handle.Enter(context);
     context.CreateBookmark(bookmarkString, this.Continue, bookmarkOptions);
}

private void Continue(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, Object obj)
{
      NoPersistHandle handle = noPersistHandle.Get(context);
      handle.Exit(context);
}
```

This solution works - but has no persistence.